# What is the intelligent way of setting the text width for a specific theorem in \newtheoremstyle?

Tags: indentation, theorems, amsthm

I'm using a `\newtheoremstyle` to generate a `\newtheorem` called **Example**. However, I want the Example (the theorem) and the text, everything, to have a smaller text width than the normal text, and I don't know the efficient way of doing this, and avoid repeating code each time.

Is there an intelligent way to do this in the `\newtheoremstyle`? Or elsewhere?

Comment: Note that it is unusual around here to have any greeting.

Answer (score 5):

The `thmtools` package can help with this.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm,thmtools}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\declaretheorem[shaded={bgcolor=white,textwidth=20em},style=definition]{Example}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{Example}
\lipsum[2]
\end{Example}
\end{document}
```

This puts the Example is a box that is 20em wide.

[image]

**Edit:**
In a comment, you mention centering for the first time. Here's a way to get centering. It takes a little bit more work.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm,thmtools}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\declaretheorem[style=definition]{Example}
\addtotheorempreheadhook[Example]{%
        \moveright\dimexpr(\linewidth-20em)/2\vbox\bgroup
                \hsize=20em
                \linewidth=\hsize
}
\addtotheorempostfoothook[Example]{\egroup}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{Example}
\lipsum[2]
\end{Example}
\end{document}
```

This doesn't rely on the `shaded` extension. Instead, it puts the theorem in a `\vbox` of the appropriate size and then moves that right `(\linewidth-20em)/2`.

Comment: Thanks, this looks like a great solution. However, I'm looking at the Thmtools Users’ Guide and can't find anything about centering that example. I want exactly what you posted, but centered. How can I do this?

Comment: @Paul: I've added a way to get centering.

Comment: thanks for your suggestions, but I find really complicated the installation of thmtools on windows. I haven't been able to implement this yet.

Comment: @Paul: I cannot help with that. I only rarely use Windows and never TeX on Windows. All I can say is it comes with TeX Live.

Comment: @TH: MikTeX works seamlessly with Windows, both its 32-bits and its 64-bits. It includes and installs thmtools